Unable to install playwright on linux (pwsh) : Exception calling "Main" with "1" argument(s):
I'm developping a .NET application for linux (Debian 12 on arm 64), but when I'm installing playwright, I have this error :
$ pwsh ./playwright.ps1 install
MethodInvocationException: /home/lds/Wendy/1v0v0/playwright.ps1:7
Line |
   7 |  exit [Microsoft.Playwright.Program]::Main($args)
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "Main" with "1" argument(s): "An error occurred trying to start process
     | '/home/lds/Wendy/1v0v0/.playwright/node/linux-arm64/node' with working directory '/home/lds/Wendy/1v0v0'.
     | Permission denied"


What is the problem, I also try with su right, but same issue....

I bet you have to check permissions.

No, I tried to set chmod 777 on all folder and sub folder. and I also tried in superuser.

OK, node was not an executable ... just set chmod +x on it ...
